# Need to transfer .apk file using webservice

Tags: android, web-services, file-upload, apk

I have converted my apk file into byte array and send it using  webservice as follows

```
 [WebMethod]
    public byte[] GetApkFile(string deviceID)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = ServiceHelper.GetTempFilePath();
            string fileName = path + "\\VersionUpdate.apk";
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
            return ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(fileStream);          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }

    }

      public byte[] ConvertStreamToByteBuffer(System.IO.Stream theStream)
    {
        int b1;
        System.IO.MemoryStream tempStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        while ((b1 = theStream.ReadByte()) != -1)
        {
            tempStream.WriteByte(((byte)b1));
        }
        return tempStream.ToArray();
    }
```

I have consumed the web service using ksoap protocol in my android application as bytes of array as given below

```
public void DownloadApkFile(String serverIPAddress,
        String deviceId) {

    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://VisionEPODWebService/GetApkFile";
    String OPERATION_NAME = "GetApkFile";
    String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "http://VisionEPODWebService/";
    String SOAP_ADDRESS = "";
    SOAP_ADDRESS = "http://" + serverIPAddress
            + "/VisionEPODWebService/SystemData.asmx";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,
            OPERATION_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER10);
    new MarshalBase64().register(envelope); 
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
    request.addProperty("deviceID", deviceId);  
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    try {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        Object response = envelope.getResponse();
        byte[] b=response.toString().getBytes();

        String fileName = "/sdcard/" + "VersionUpdate" + ".apk";

       FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = 
                  new FileOutputStream(fileName); 
        fileOuputStream.write(b);
        fileOuputStream.close();           

    }

    catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.toString();           
    }
```

The problem is that I am not getting the exact apk file after converting byte array[] back to file.

Will anyone please review the code and please tell me is there any bug in this.

My need to  get the converted byte[] apk file back to .apk file in the sdcard for installation.

Answer (score 1):

`response.toString()` is likely not a String representation of your APK.

Try the following:

```
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
byte[] b=result.toString().getBytes();
```

Comment: I have tried it...but the problem is that i am converting the file using dot net webservice.So when it come to java part it cannot parse to back to apk file .If it is Java to java communication it will be possible.